# How might I implement a react-native-draggable-flatlist as a function component instead of a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

### Update

Resolved after changing "setData({ data })" to "setData(data)" and restarting iOS Simulator

### Original Post

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable-flatlist example uses a class component but I'd prefer to use a function component. My attempt at implementing as a function component is below, but I am running into an error (also below). The error occurs after reordering a single list item, then the list disappears.

### Function Component Attempt

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import DraggableFlatList from 'react-native-draggable-flatlist';
import ScreenTitle from '../components/ScreenTitle';
import AppScreen from './AppScreen';

function MyMorningScreen(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      order: 1,
      label: 'Start Timeular',
    },
    {
      order: 2,
      label: 'Workout',
    },
    {
      order: 3,
      label: 'Shower',
    },
  ]);

  const renderItem = ({ item, index, drag, isActive }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onLongPress={drag}>
      <Text>{item.label}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
  return (
    <AppScreen style={styles.screen}>
      <ScreenTitle title="My Morning" />
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <DraggableFlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          onDragEnd={({ data }) => setData({ data })}
        />
      </View>
    </AppScreen>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default MyMorningScreen;
```

### Error

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.props.data.forEach...')]
- node_modules/react-native-draggable-flatlist/lib/index.js:192:20 in __generator$argument_1
* http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:135784:24 in step
* http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:135686:72 in <unknown>
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:200:22 in doResolve
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:66:11 in Promise
* http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:135665:35 in <unknown>
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15732:12 in commitLifeCycles
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18744:22 in commitLayoutEffects
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:265:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:476:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18483:29 in commitRootImpl
* [native code]:null in commitRootImpl
- node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18317:17 in commitRoot
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17697:12 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
* [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5321:31 in runWithPriority$argument_1
- node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5316:21 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5304:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17125:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11003:16 in dispatchAction
* [native code]:null in dispatchAction
* app/screens/MyMorningScreen.js:36:21 in DraggableFlatList.props.onDragEnd
* http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:136087:19 in <unknown>
- node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/core/AnimatedCall.js:9:15 in listener
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working App: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@therketan/draggablelist)

[image]

```js
// Try updating state like shown below: 
/*.....*/
onDragEnd={({ data }) => setData(data)}
```

**UPDATED Full Code with Checkbox implementation:**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  CheckBox,
} from 'react-native';
import DraggableFlatList from 'react-native-draggable-flatlist';

const initialData = [
  {
    order: 1,
    label: 'Start Timeular',
    isCheked: false,
  },
  {
    order: 2,
    label: 'Workout',
    isCheked: false,
  },
  {
    order: 3,
    label: 'Shower',
    isCheked: true,
  },
];
function MyMorningScreen(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);

  const renderItem = ({ item, index, drag, isActive }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <TouchableOpacity onLongPress={drag}>
        <Text>{item?.label}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <CheckBox
        value={item.isCheked}
        onChange={() => {
          handleCheck(item.label);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );

  const handleCheck = (label) => {
    let updated = [...data];
    updated = updated.map((task, index) => {
      if (label === task.label) {
        return { ...task, isCheked: !task.isCheked };
      }
      return task;
    });
    setData(updated);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <DraggableFlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          onDragEnd={({ data }) => setData(data)}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    marginTop: 24,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#212121',
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginTop: 10,
    padding: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
});

export default MyMorningScreen;
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm struggling to get state to update via the renderItem function onPress attribute. Building a checkbox.

Comment: It won't be that difficult. Just post an questions someone will help you.

Comment: Just realized you implemented the checkbox! I was trying to do onPress={() => (item.checked = !item.checked)} inside TouchableOpacity. Why did that not work? seemed like the component would not re-render until I long pressed it.

Comment: Just FYI: **the link to the working App is broken:** "_Oops!
We couldn't find the Snack you're looking for. Go to the homepage._"